# How to toggle a single item in an ember list in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a component as follows

```
{{#md-collection content=model as |item|}}
  <div class='collection-item'>
    <img src="{{item.url}}" class="asset-thumbnail" />
    <div class="asset-url">
      {{item.url}}
    </div>
    <div class="secondary-content">
      {{#copy-button
         clipboardText=item.url
         class="btn"
         success="successfulCopy"
      }}
        {{fa-icon "chain" title="Copy to Clipboard"}} {{unless copied "Copy Link" "Copied"}}
      {{/copy-button}}
      {{confirmation-link
        title="Delete"
        action=(route-action "deleteAsset" item)
        icon="trash"
        message="Are you sure you want to delete this asset?"
        confirmButtonText="Yes, Delete Asset"
        confirmButtonColor="#FF6666"
        classNames="btn delete"}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/md-collection}}
```

and it has the controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  copied:false,
  actions:{
    deleteAsset(asset){
      this.attrs.deleteAsset(asset);
    },
    successfulCopy(btn){
      console.log(this.$(btn));
      this.$(btn).toggleProperty('copied', true);
      Ember.run.later(()=>{
        this.$(btn).toggleProperty('copied', false);
      },500);
    }
  }
});
```

when I click the button with the text `Copy Link`, the component then toggles the copied property as it should, however, it is toggling the property for all of the items in the list changing all of their text. In the action `successfulCopy` I have a reference to the HTML of the button that was clicked. How would I toggle the copied property for just that one component to only toggle that button's text?

Comment: You need to have one attribute per button called `copied`. Right now you have one attribute shared between all buttons, then whenever that attribute is changed it will have a chain reaction within all elements which are using it...

Comment: You posted Component code, is that `copy-button` component code?. show us the code, from where are you calling `successfulCopy` function what is that argument is it clicked `copy-button` component this context.

Answer (score 0):

main-component,

```
  {{#copy-button
     clipboardText=item.url
     class="btn"
     success="successfulCopy" as |copied|
  }}
    {{fa-icon "chain" title="Copy to Clipboard"}} {{unless copied "Copy Link" "Copied"}}
  {{/copy-button}}
```

**copy-button.hbs**
`copied` property is available in `copy-button` component, so to access it `main-component` it should yield it.

```
{{yield copied}}
```

**copy-button.js**
`successfulCopy` function will toggle his own property `copied`. so you dont need to pass argument and you dont require jquery stuff, since you have already written logic based `copied` property. just toggling `copied` will do the rest.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init(){
     this._super(...arguments);
     this.set('copied',false);
   }
  actions:{
    deleteAsset(asset){
      this.get('deleteAsset')(asset);
    },
    successfulCopy(){
      this.toggleProperty('copied');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
successfulCopy(btn){
  this.set('item.copied', true)
}

{{fa-icon "chain" title="Copy to Clipboard"}} {{unless item.copied "Copy Link" "Copied"}}
```